# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller.getResolver()

Tags: java, maven, castor

I am trying to make a simple SIF call in a maven project -
at line

```
resp = (SearchQueryResponse) sipClient.process(req);
```

getting the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller.getResolver()Lorg/exolab/castor/xml/ClassDescriptorResolver;
    at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.setMappingLoader(CastorUtil.java:470)
    at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:358)
    at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:323)
    at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:309)
    at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:295)
    at com.siperian.sif.client.HttpSiperianClient._process(HttpSiperianClient.java:117)
    at com.siperian.sif.client.SiperianClient.process(SiperianClient.java:179)
```

I have deleted multiple versions of castor dependencies in .m2 folder and updated maven. Cleaned the project and still the error wont go away, below is the maven dependency tree
[image]

I can see the getresolver method in castoe.xml jar file
When I look at the stack trace - where getResolver is called - it is pointing to castor.XML's method.

[image: getResolver method]

[image: classDescriptorResolver.class]

Comment: try using some older version of jar and see if it works!

Comment: I have included 1.1.1 version castor XML jar as external dependency as it is not getting automatically downloaded from Maven central repository. It started working. 
Thanks!